# Tyring to access MariaDB running in a docker container on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, mysql, docker, mariadb

I can't seem to remotely connect to my database, via SSH tunnel. I'm relatively new to all this, so I was hoping someone might be able to give me some pointers.

I've got a cloud server on which I've installed Docker, and I'm running a database container (for another service, Wordpress):

compose.yaml

```
services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_root_password
      - db_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - 3306
```

The database container works just fine, and the rest of my Docker services interact with the database with no issues.

If I connect to the remote machine via SSH, I can access the database within the Docker environment via a MariaDB client on the host, as the port 3306 is forwarded from the Docker container to the host:

```
➜  ssh -i mykey user@hostname

➜  docker compose up -d

➜  nc -vz localhost 3306
Connection to localhost (::1) 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!

➜  mariadb -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 15
Server version: 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

However I'm not able to use my local database client (DBeaver). I've setup SSH tunneling in the client with the same credentials I use to connect to the host via CLI.

Testing the SSH connection within my DB client is successful. However once the SSH tunnel is established, the connection to the database fails:

```
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:31987 : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
```

Would anyone be able to give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?
Is this the right way to go about remotely accessing the database?

Am I making some bad assumptions about how SSH tunneling works? I assumed that once the tunnel is established, it would connect to port 3306 on my remote host, as if the client were actually on the remote host. I'm also not sure where port '31987' comes from, but I'm guessing it's the ephemeral port used by the client to connect to port 3306, but perhaps I'm also wrong about that?

I don't want the database port publicly accessible, so remote access to port 3306 on my remote host is firewalled.

I'm aware that I can install a new docker service, sshtunnel, and just tunnel into that, but I don't see why I cannot connect when tunneled into the host...

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Show the command you used for the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use network_mode host in your docker-compose. Because by default docker creates a seperate network which is very difficult to tunnel to.

```
    services:
    
      db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: database
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
          MYSQL_USER: wordpress
          MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
        secrets:
          - db_root_password
          - db_password
networks:
      proxy:
        aliases:
          - test.mysql.docker


sshtunnel:
    restart: always
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/openssh-server
    container_name: sshtunnel
    ports:
      - 2222:2222
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/etc/tunnel/id_rsa.pub
      - ./openssh/sshd_config:/config/ssh_host_keys/sshd_config
    environment:
      - PUBLIC_KEY_FILE=/etc/tunnel/id_rsa.pub
      - USER_NAME=proxy
      - SUDO_ACCESS=true
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
    name: proxy
```

See here:
https://madewithlove.com/blog/using-an-ssh-tunnel-to-connect-to-your-dev-mysql-with-docker/

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried this and it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.
Would a more correct solution thus be to create an sshtunnel service within my docker compose?

Comment: Yes that's an option I will edit my post to show you how

Comment: Edit my post based on https://madewithlove.com/blog/using-an-ssh-tunnel-to-connect-to-your-dev-mysql-with-docker/

Comment: Thanks again!
If you wouldn't mind, it leads me to another question: Is the way I'm going about this "wrong"? How would remote database access for a docker container on a remote machine normally be implemented (in a business context)?

I've been trying to avoid web-interfaces, such as phpmyadmin, for security reasons, but having to implement a second ssh server dedicated to database access feels like a solution required because I've done something wrong in my design...

Comment: I haven't seen databases running in docker containers yet in my 15 years of experience , so I can't help you with that.   In my experience usually databases run on a seperate database server, or using a PaaS service like Azure SQL. And usually remote access is done via VPN like OpenVPN or wireguard. Or a dedicated vpn appliance. But as long as you harden it properly there is nothing wrong it I think, and maybe implement the CIS benchmarks for docker and containers. But with doing an ssh tunnel your making it yourself a bit more difficult, I think using a VPN makes it easier to connect

Comment: Shall I make another answer with how I would do it with a VPN?

Comment: I also created an chat room for this https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151182/mariadb-remote-access-docker

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access your chat, I'm too new (don't have enough 'rep'). But I certainly appreciate your help! Thanks ever so much.
I'll take a look at adding a VPN to my server instead.

I'll also strongly consider what you say about the database normally being hosted outside of Docker; it ties up with my findings when experimenting with Azure, the database being a completely separate service to the application containers.

I feel like getting experience in cloud dev is particularly difficult if you don't work for a large corporate entity... It's not as simple as searching anymore!

Comment: You don't need to add a VPN to your server you can run a VPN inside a docker container.